# What is the correct way to mock the ReCaptcha component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, formik

I have the following component which is being used as part of a Formik form.

```
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import React from "react";

const reCaptchaRef: any = React.createRef();

export const isReCaptchaVerified = () => {
    const reCaptchaValue = reCaptchaRef.current.getValue()
    return reCaptchaValue ? 'true' : 'false'
}

export const resetReCaptcha = () => {
    return reCaptchaRef.current.reset();
}

const ReCaptcha = () => {
    return (
        <ReCAPTCHA
            ref={reCaptchaRef}
            sitekey="Your client site key"
        />
    )
}

export default ReCaptcha
```

I am using JestJS and I am mocking the above component as follows:

```
jest.mock('@components/ReCaptcha', () => ({
    isReCaptchaVerified: 'true'
}));
```

But each time I run the test it it errors out the following:

> Error: Uncaught [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

This is how the component is being used inside Formik:

```
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form noValidate id="contact-form">
            <Field
                type="text"
                name="fullName"
                dataTestId="fullName"
                inputName="fullName"
                labelText="Full Name"
            />
            <Field
                type="text"
                name="email"
                dataTestId="email"
                inputName="email"
                labelText="email Address"
            />
        <Recaptcha />
        </Form>
    </Formik>
```

what I am missing here?